# How do I get data out of a callback without using a global variable?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures, addeventlistener

I created a simplified version of my code below.

```
var translation = 0;

function main() {
    // load images

    loopClosure(images);
}

function loopClosure(images) {
    // setup webgl

    function render() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

        // use translation here to update image locations
    }

    render();
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyboardHandler, false);

function keyboardHandler(event) {
    if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
        translation--;
    }
    if (event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
        translation++;
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of the translation global variable? Is there a way to update a variable based on an event without using a global variable?

Comment: Wrap everything within an IIFE. You can't replace the outer scope variable in this case, but that doesn't have to be a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nik020 points out you can use a closure. An Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) creates a closure but it doesn't have to be the IIFE pattern. A normal named function will do the same thing

```
function main() { 
    var translation = 0;

    function main() {
        // load images

        loopClosure(images);
    }

    function loopClosure(images) {
        // setup webgl

        function render() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

            // use translation here to update image locations
        }

        render();
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyboardHandler, false);

    function keyboardHandler(event) {
        if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
            translation--;
        }
        if (event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
            translation++;
        }
    }
}

main();
```

The IIFE pattern just means you don't have to think up a name and the name will not conflict with other names.

You can also bind `this`.  Example

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.translation = 0;
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyboardHandler.bind(this), false);
  }
  keyboardHandler(event) {
    if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
        this.translation--;
    }
    if (event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
        this.translation++;
    }
  }
}

const app = new App();
```

You use arrow functions which are syntactic sugar for binding `this`

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.translation = 0;
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
          this.translation--;
      }
      if (event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
          this.translation++;
      }
    }, false);
  }
}

const app = new App();
```

If you want to be able to remove the listener and you're using an arrow function or a bind you can store the function reference in a variable

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.translation = 0;
    const keyboardHandler = (event) => {
      if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
          this.translation--;
      }
      if (event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
          this.translation++;
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyboardHandler, false);
  }
}

const app = new App();
```

There's 4 to 10 more ways to [bind this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and/or [make a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Answer (score 3):

I don't speak english very well, but I'll try.

The var `translation` is in a good place, if you want this variable cannot be accessed from outside. you can create IIFE for create scope.

```
(function () { 
    var translation = 0;

    function main() {
        // load images

        loopClosure(images);
    }

    function loopClosure(images) {
        // setup webgl

        function render() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

            // use translation here to update image locations
        }

        render();
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyboardHandler, false);

    function keyboardHandler(event) {
        if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
            translation--;
        }
        if (event.key == 'ArrowRight') {
            translation++;
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: FYI for user1801359: IIFE = Immediately Invoked Function Expression